# Unknown reason of logs on iPad (not iPhone)

Tags: ios, ipad, logging

I am using images in my iOS application.

When I test my app on iPad, Xcode return that logs:

> *** -[__NSCFString stringByAppendingPathExtension:]: cannot append
>   extension 'png' to path '~iPad@2x'

What it means?

p.s. When I test my app on iPhone, Xcode dont return that logs.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the code calling `stringByAppendingPathExtension:`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking for if Device is iPad and then set the image by appending "@2x" then Dont. Just use image name without '@2x'. This might solve your problem.

Like if you are setting an image for iPhone UI like

```
UIImageView * imageView = [UIImageView alloc] init];
[imageView setImage[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
```

And for iPad you are doing this:

```
[imageView setImage[UIImage imageNamed:@"image@2x.png"]];
```

Then this might be the problem. Dont append @2x.